# Empty image as class variable

Tags: python, numpy

I want to declare an image as a class variable in order to use it with different method.

Is `frame = None` an acceptable way in python? Otherwise what is the best way?

Comment: Setting `frame = None` has nothing to do with whatever image handling you want to do, unless you have a function that is prepared to see `frame` have a value of `None`. Python doesn't have variable *declarations*, only definitions, and you can write a function that *uses* a name as long as the name is defined by the time the function is *called*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a variable `frame` and set its value to `None`. You can later assign it any other value that you need, for example, a class as your program requires.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

frame = None
frame = A()
print(frame)
```

**Output:**

```
<__main__.A object at 0x7fdfff4804c0>
```